# Log4j RollingFileAppender every minute

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, rollingfileappender

I'm testing Log4j RollingFileAppender with log4j 2.6.2.

I want to rotate the logs every minute and so I have a log4j2.xml very similar to one example of here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender.
This is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="testlog4j2" packages="">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">C:/tmp/testlog4</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"
          filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0/1 * * * ?"/>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
          <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz" />
          <IfLastModified age="60d" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="ALL">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And this is an app where I write a log every second.

```
package testlog4j2;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLog4j {

    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestLog4j.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (int i=1; i<=240; i++) {
                logger.info("Hello");
                Thread.sleep(1*1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Excepcion general", e);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is:

- once the system rotates the log at the first minute appears continuously errors like this

  2016-07-28 15:10:02,015 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to move file C:\tmp\testlog4\2016-07\app-2016-07-28-15-10.log.gz to C:\tmp\testlog4\2016-07\app-2016-07-28-15-10.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException C:\tmp\testlog4\2016-07\app-2016-07-28-15-10.log.gz -> C:\tmp\testlog4\2016-07\app-2016-07-28-15-10.log.gz
- There isn't a gz for every minute
- The result gz don't have a log with 60 lines. Instead they have 1, 2 or three lines of log.
- The main log C:\tmp\testlog4\app.log has no content

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have found a bug. Please raise a bug report on the [Jira issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2) with all the details you describe here.

Answer (score 0):

By now It seems to work with TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy instead of CronTriggeringPolicy.

My conf looks now like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="testlog4j2" packages="">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">C:/tmp/testlog4</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"
          filePattern="${baseDir}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
      <!-- 
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
      -->
      <!-- 
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0/1 * * * ?"/>
       -->
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/><!-- como el filePattern tiene como unidad minima el minuto, se hara cada 1 minutos -->
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="0">
          <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log" />
          <IfLastModified age="2M" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="ALL">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The delete is not working by now but that's another story I will investigate next.

Best regards

Comment: The delete works now with this <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="1">
  <IfFileName glob="app-*.log" />
 <IfLastModified age="2m" />
</Delete>